# Wierdly behaving cylinder in modelling

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, vertices, edges

While modelling hand of Lego man, i found something really weird.

The cylinder i created in it contained all the vertices of the individual circle loops things inside it(At least that's what it looked like,see in the image)

[image: Notice all the vertices present]

But in the object mode, i see disconnected loops in that cylinder like shown in the image below. I'm not really sure why that is happening, and after messing around for a while i decided to ask it here.Thanks.

[image: Notice those Disconnected Loops]